# Import-csv with different delimiters and quotes in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file using different quote and text delimiter characters other than the default. I know for the delimiter there is an option for a different delimiter but I cannot find out how to get rid of the quote characters.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\test.txt' -Delimiter "(character U+0014 is used here, won't show here)"
```

But the quote character is the U+00FE and I need to remove this as well so I can get the text without any special characters. I do not want to write this out to a new file. I want to import the csv into a variable so I can do some analytic's on it. For example see if a field is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delimiter is not actually a problem, as you can do that with

```
-Delimiter "$([char]0x14)"
```

As for the quotes you can use a preprocessing step and then use `ConvertFrom-` instead of `Import-CSV`:

```
Get-Content test.txt |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ([char]0xFE) } | # to remove the “quotes”
    ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter "$([char]0x14)"
```

If your lines contain embedded quotes then it needs a bit more work and probably easier just to force-quote every field:

```
$14 = "$([char]0x14)"
$_ -replace ([char]0xFE) -replace '"', '""' -replace "(?<=^|$14)|(?=`$|$14)", '"'
```

Comment: Just a minor note--these two lines are equivalent when used with Import-Csv (so I presume ConvertFrom-Csv as well): `-Delimiter "$([char]0x14)"` and `-Delimiter 0x14` so no need to use the more complicated form.

Comment: @msorens: Oh, nice. I didn't actually test it, to be honest but I know the string-interpolated form to work. Apparently since `-Delimiter` requires a `char` PowerShell auto-converts to the right thing (it wouldn't if it were a string).